# access javascript variable in java

Tags: javascript

```
function test(custId){
    List<Account> list=accountDelegate.findAccountEntityByGroupId((long)%>
        custId<%)%>;
    <script>
}
```

Here my question is how to send custId to java method as parameter from Javascript? Where java method takes long argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define if you are passing to a JSP page, or an Applet.

Some information on passing variables via applet:

1. http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0183.html
2. http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread93030.html

Apparently it's not possible to go Javascript to Java, unless you use querystring/cookies, things like that.  Same applies with JSP pages, because there is a distinction between client side and server side, you will need to design your application so it utilises cookies/querystring/form values to achieve this.